# CSS Liquid column width

Tags: css

I'm working on a widget requiring this layout:

[image]

Let's imagine each item shown above is the same widget but with different overall width.

The dark green parts are the widget items, arranged in columns of a specific width.

My problem is achieving liquid spacing, ie, the light green area, between each column.

Also note that when the widget can't accommodate each item, it throws them on the next line - typically achieved with CSS `float:left`.

It is important that this remains liquid since the widget width changes according to window width.

**Edit:** What I need seems to be justifying span elements (as opposed to text). I tried using CSS `text-align: justify;`, but [it failed](http://jsfiddle.net/Beqgy/3/).

Answer (score 1):

I think `text-align: justify;` technique will be perfect for you.

A live example of it can be seen here - http://jsfiddle.net/xbmkr/7/.

Notice that the distance between the red blocks here is automatic, not set by any `margin`s. Try setting the width of the `inline-block` `li`s to 30% or 20% to get a better idea ;)

Comment: what is important to understand here is that `display: inline-block;` will **not** be applied if you use `float: left` later. Floats are rendered as blocks and the `display` property will not be applied!!! This answers your failure that you show here: http://jsfiddle.net/Beqgy/3/

Comment: Strange, in my jsfiddle, `text-align` failed.

Comment: @Christian, did you happen to read my comment to my answer? )))

Answer (score 0):

You could try a percentage margin: http://jsfiddle.net/6w2qj/1/